# Loading Obj files in Libgdx not working on android

Tags: java, android, file-io, opengl-es, libgdx

The following code shows a torus slowly revolving and coming into display:

```
package com.objloader.example;

import ...
public class ObjLoaderProg implements ApplicationListener{
    String torus;
    Mesh model;
    private PerspectiveCamera camera;
    @Override
    public void create() {
        InputStream stream=null;
        try {
            stream = new FileInputStream(Gdx.files.internal("data/torus.obj").path());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        model = ObjLoader.loadObj(stream, true);
        Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        Gdx.gl10.glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-3.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    protected int lastTouchX;
    protected int lastTouchY;
    protected float rotateZ=0.01f;
    protected float increment=0.01f;

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        camera.apply(Gdx.gl10);
        Gdx.gl10.glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-3.0f);
        Gdx.gl10.glRotatef(rotateZ, rotateZ, 5.0f, rotateZ);
        model.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES);

         if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
              lastTouchX = Gdx.input.getX();
              lastTouchY = Gdx.input.getY();
            } else if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
              camera.rotate(0.2f * (lastTouchX - Gdx.input.getX()), 0, 1.0f, 0);
              camera.rotate(0.2f * (lastTouchY - Gdx.input.getY()), 1.0f, 0, 0);

              lastTouchX = Gdx.input.getX();
              lastTouchY = Gdx.input.getY();
            }
         rotateZ+=increment;
         System.out.println(""+rotateZ);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int arg0, int arg1) {
        float aspectRatio = (float) arg0 / (float) arg1;
        camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, 2f * aspectRatio, 2f);
        camera.near=0.1f;
        camera.translate(0, 0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

It renders a torus obj that's saved in the data folder, and by clicking and dragging on the screen the user can rotate the camera.

This works fine on the desktop, but when I try to run it on android, I get a NullPointerException at:

model.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES);

I've tried placing torus.obj just inside assets, and within assets/data. I'm using libgdx 0.9.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are referring to `model.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES);`. I believe you have two problems. First, **model** is null because you are catching a FileNotFoundException and ignoring it. I suggest you don't catch the FileNotFoundException right now, let it crash, and look at the stack trace. That will give you a better indication of why this failing. Note that e.printStackTrace() is not useful for debugging on android, try using the gdx log.

The second problem is that I suspect the path/stream is actually going to the wrong place.  Instead of creating a FileInputStream, use the FileHandle.read() function. It returns a java.io.InputStream that you can pass to ObjLoader.loadObj().

```
in = Gdx.files.internal("data/torus.obj").read();
model ObjLoader.loadObj(in);
in.close();
```

The difference between this and your code is that FileHandle.read() in libgdx's android backend uses the android [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html%20AssestManager) to open files that are bundled with the program.

Finally, copy the torus.obj file to <YourAndroidProject>/assets/data/torus.obj.

An aside: if you specify the line number, please provide the full file otherwise the line will be off. Line 52 of the code you have provided is: `lastTouchY = Gdx.input.getY();`. Note the "import ..." at the beginning of your code. Those imports affect the line number.